# How to stop a fluid action (beginner question)

Tags: physics, baking, fluid-simulation

I'm only partially a "beginner"  I've done editing in Premiere, and a lot of 3-D shapes and camera movement in Blender.

I am learning to do a "Text Melt" and all is going well.  However, I want it to stop the "baking" after about 4 seconds, since it is so CPU intensive, and the melt physics is no longer needed.

Here's the dope sheet that I've got as it stands now:

[image]

1. The text is there until frame 90, I don't want to start until then.
2. The domain is disabled until frame 90, where I want it to start the melting.
3. Then they swap.  The text is hidden, and the domain commences to do the melt, with some changes in viscosity, until frame 210.  (The domain is set to "liquid" and frame 90-210)
   So far, this all looks good.

But at frame 210, I just need the physics to stop.  But if the frames after 210 aren't "baked" then that domain cylinder reappears.
If I set the domain frame end to something past 210, it continues to "bake" those frames (very tedious and time consuming)

In summary, and simply put, I just want something like a freeze frame for the physics after 210. But I don't know how to tell it "That last frame is fine, just keep it there."

Is it possible?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copy the domain on your last frame where it should freeze, then convert the copied object to mesh (object -> convert to mesh).
Then animate visibility of your animated mesh to the last frame, then make it invisible and the copied object visible.

[image]
[image]

result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes... and no.   "Copy the domain on your last frame..."   And do what?  I selected it after the baking is complete , frame 210...  (it's a blob).  And Ctrl-C in the viewport.   Then paste it where?  I advance to frame 211, and Ctrl-V in the viewport and I get the cylinder domain back.   And there is a "Domain.001 in the scene collection, which is the cylinder, not the melted blob.   Assuming the pasted Domain.001 was really a blob, setting visibility to swap at frame 210-211 is understandable.

Comment: Doh!   Sorry.  Paste the copy on the same frame (frame 210), then convert to mesh, remove those extra keyframes, set visible, etc.

Works great!  Thanks!